# Javascript Focus() function not working

Tags: javascript

I have a textbox which I want to set the focus on, but it doesn't work.

```
document.getElementById("txtCity").focus();
```

Any idea?

Comment: What does the html for the textbox look like?

Comment: Is `document.getElementById("txtCity")` returning `undefined`? Any JavaScript errors in a console? What browser? Is the element actually focusable? **Show more code.**

Comment: Using IE8. No errors on the page.

Comment: for example Fx will not do a getElementById on <input NAME="txtCity" - it needs an ID to do getElementById, but IE will work

Comment: We need more code, since this basic command clearly works. http://jsfiddle.net/kBxA4/2/

Comment: I see my mistake now. I did something wrong. You are right. It does work. I appreciate your help.

Comment: What was your mistake? Please explain in an answer you write yourself, so we can see and learn. If you don't want to, please delete this entire question, it is of no use to let only a snap of code with an unanswered/unanswerable question linger around.

Comment: In my case the input was disabled, making it not focusable

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Maybe you are calling the JavaScript before the input element is rendered? Position the input element before the JavaScript or wait until the page is loaded before you trigger your JavaScript.

In that order, it works just fine:

```
<input type="text" id="test" />
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById("test").focus();
</script>
```

In [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) you could place your code within the [`.ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) method to execute your code first when the DOM is fully loaded:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#test").focus();
    // document.getElementById("test").focus();
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 15):

In case someone searching has a similar situation to mine ... I had to set a `tabindex` attribute before my `div` could receive `focus()`:

```
featured.setAttribute('tabindex', '0');
featured.focus();
console.log(document.activeElement===featured); // true
```

(I found my answer here: [Make div element receive focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16261504/make-div-element-receive-focus) )

***And of course, make sure the body element is ready before setting focus to a child element.***

Answer (score 9):

I have also faced same problem.To resolve this problem, put your code in setTimeout function.

```
function showMeOnClick() {
    // Set text filed focus after some delay
    setTimeout(function() { jQuery('#searchTF').focus() }, 20);
    // Do your work.....
}
```

Comment: Doing this with a timeout is just quick&dirty

Comment: Yes, adding timeout is just a workaround because we need a next tick kind of event to repaint the DOM to show the changes. We can opt another approach to solving this problem :-)

Comment: I solved it by applying an "animationend" listener for the created object's animation (because my object appears with an animation). This way it gets the focus once it is where it's supposed to be.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem as Martin Buberl mentioned [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798579/javascript-focus-function-not-working/4798626#4798626), the element did not exist on the moment I gave `focus()`. I used `window.requestAnimationFrame()` to give a callback which will give focus on the next render.

```js
window.requestAnimationFrame(() => elm.focus())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap it into document ready function and be sure, that you have jquery included.

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
       $(document).ready(function() {
          $("#test").focus();
       });
    </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    <div id="txtROSComments" contenteditable="true" onkeyup="SentenceCase(this, event)"style="border: 1px solid black; height: 200px; width: 200px;">
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function SentenceCase(inField, e) {
            debugger;
            var charCode;

            if (e && e.which) {
                charCode = e.which;
            } else if (window.event) {
                e = window.event;
                charCode = e.keyCode;
            }

            if (charCode == 190) {
                format();
            }
        }

        function format() {
            debugger; ;
            var result = document.getElementById('txtROSComments').innerHTML.split(".");

            var finaltxt = "";


            var toformat = result[result.length - 2];

            result[0] = result[0].substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + result[0].slice(1);

            if (toformat[0] != " ") {

                for (var i = 0; i < result.length - 1; i++) {
                    finaltxt += result[i] + ".";
                }

                document.getElementById('txtROSComments').innerHTML = finaltxt;
                alert(finaltxt);
                abc();
                return finaltxt;
            }



            if (toformat[0].toString() == " ") {
                debugger;
                var upped = toformat.substring(1, 2).toUpperCase();

                var formatted = " " + upped + toformat.slice(2);

                for (var i = 0; i < result.length - 1; i++) {

                    if (i == (result.length - 2)) {
                        finaltxt += formatted + ".";
                    }
                    else {
                        finaltxt += result[i] + ".";
                    }

                }
            }
            else {
                debugger;
                var upped = toformat.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();

                var formatted = " " + upped + toformat.slice(1);



                for (var i = 0; i < result.length - 1; i++) {
                    if (i == (result.length - 2)) {
                        finaltxt += formatted + ".";
                    }
                    else {
                        //if(i
                        finaltxt += result[i] + ".";
                    }

                }

            }
            debugger;
            document.getElementById('txtROSComments').value = finaltxt;
            return finaltxt;

        }

    </script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       function abc() {
           document.getElementById("#txtROSComments").focus();
       }
```

Comment: It's great to have some code, but it would be great if you could add a bit of explanation.

Comment: I'm not sure how to find the answer to the question in this code.