# Make div element receive focus

Tags: javascript, html

How can I make an HTML `<div>` element receive focus, so elements will be put into focus when `focus()` is called on them?

Comment: You mean, so the `div` element can receive focus? HTML `tabindex="0"` JS `elRef.tabIndex = 0;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to focus on a <div> using javascript focus() function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656467/is-it-possible-to-focus-on-a-div-using-javascript-focus-function)

Comment: Please read from https://gist.github.com/jamiewilson/c3043f8c818b6b0ccffd, not every html element is focusable by default.

Comment: After adding tabIndex as 0 on div, access the div element by getElementsByClassName or getElementById then call focus() into it.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Set the `tabindex="0"` on the `div`, on the assumption that you want the `div`s to receive focus, rather than child elements.

Updated the answer to add a JS Fiddle demo, showing a JavaScript means of achieving this:

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
for (var i = 0, len = divs.length; i < len; i++){
    divs[i].setAttribute('tabindex', '0');
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/XWhJG/1/).

While composing the demo I found that `tabindex="-1"` allows the element to receive mouse-clicks to assign focus, but not keyboard events (through the <kbd>tab</kbd> button), however (and as implied in the comment, earlier, by [Fabricio Matté](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16261504/make-div-element-receive-focus/16261525#comment23268982_16261504), a `tabindex="0"` allows for both). So I've used that in the demo, and updated the original answer to reflect that change.

Behavior of `tabindex="0"` versus `tabindex="-1"` documented here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/Keyboard-navigable_JavaScript_widgets#Using_tabindex

Comment: `tabindex="-1"` also allows you to focus the element with javascript by using `element.focus()`